# How to make links to the new Google Maps, with coordinates

Tags: html, google-maps

Google recently changed Google Maps UI, and now the links I use does not work anymore.
I've tried searching, but I haven't been able to find info om how i should build links to the new Google Maps. I only find info on integration, and static image maps, which still works, but I want to be able to click on the image to get to the full Google Maps.

This is the format I used earlier:

https://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&t=h&q=loc:48.854013+2.350232

Does anyone know how I can get that work again, or preferably, a link to the entire documentation?

Comment: The link works for me. What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: I'm just getting a globe with a pointer in the middle of USA. The URL also changes to a different format.

Comment: @putvande link does not work if New G maps is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API for [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

check the new link structure.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view
  ?key=API_KEY
  &center=37.4218,-122.0840
  &zoom=18
  &maptype=satellite
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find any info about the parameters on the link you provided.

Eg. what is "4200m/data=.."?

Also, maps link you provided does not show a pointer? And I would also like to hide the explore photo bar at the bottom if possible.

Comment: @JamesB you need to look at Optional parameters https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters

Comment: Isn't that for embedding google maps to your own site? I don't need to do that, i only want a simple link sending users to google's own site, without any requirements for API key...

Comment: @JamesB you can open that link via anchor tag, as there is not API for link as you was using before. for that you need to crack new maps url structure that i pasted before.